# Handling blank query results, ISNULL(NULLIF())

Tags: sql, sql-server

Im trying to return the results of a query into a variable  to I am able to use it in a insert statement. However my select keeps returning null even though I believe I have the `ISNULL(NULLIF())` set up correctly.

```
declare @test varchar(10)

set @test =  (select ISNULL(NULLIF(discnumber,''),'NA')
from discmaster
where meteredfilename =  '3501' or nonmeteredfilename='3501')

select @test
```

It seems correct but still returns a `NULL` value. Would you Select Case but not 100% sure on that method either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd move the `ISNULL` outside of the subquery - what if the subquery returns no results?

```
set @test =  COALESCE(
           (select NULLIF(discnumber,'')
              from discmaster
              where meteredfilename =  '3501' or nonmeteredfilename='3501')
       ,'NA')
```

(I've also been a snob and replaced `ISNULL` with `COALESCE`. Outside of a few scenarios, `COAELSCE` is the better function).

Comment: Agreed, it's probably a query that returns no rows. But: why do you say that `COALESCE` is fundamentally better than `ISNULL`?

Comment: @Philip - because it generalizes to more than 2 parameters, and the return type is based on both (or all) parameter types (i.e. it uses the type precedence rules) rather than trying to coerce the second argument's type to that of the first. E.g. `select ISNULL(CAST(null as CHAR(2)),'abc')` returns `'ab'`.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever what do you mean by return type is based on all parameter types?  how does that compare with isnull?  If I have a varchar in one param and an int in the other, what return type is it?  or varbinary,varchar, int?

Comment: @FistOfFury - I gave one example in my previous comment - if you have `ISNULL(char(2),varchar(50))`, you'll get a `char(2)` result. `COALESCE(char(2),varchar(50))` will return a `varchar(50)`. For `varchar,int`, it will force it to be a `varchar` (which may be what you want, but I'd prefer to follow the usual precedence rules and insert explicit conversions if I don't want an `int` result)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `ISNULL(NULLIF(discnumber,''),'NA')`

try `COALESCE(discnumber,'NA')`

Comment: the select statement still returns a blank value using Coalesce

Comment: what sort of SQL field is discnumber? Can you supply the table definition for discmaster?